# Loader-Class - SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context

Tags: actionscript-3, security, flash-cs5, loader

I try to "catch" this error when I'm loading some images.
The following code is an test-case for my problem to secure that there are no errors in the surrounding code.

```
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

loadImage ();
function loadImage (): void {
            var _imageLoader = new Loader();
            _imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, imageSecurityErrorEventListener);
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("this-image-not-exits.jpg");

            _imageLoader.load(request);
}

function imageSecurityErrorEventListener (e:SecurityErrorEvent) {
    trace ("This is my own trace for the Security Error");
}
```

I know that there are lot's of posts and questions in the www and here, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I'm working on an interactiv-movie with many images and movies which are loaded dynamically in the application.

In this snipped I generated the worst case in my application (try to load an image that not exits).
When I run this code I get the trace "SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context" and not the trace of my the Listener.
Do you have any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That specific security error is **thrown** rather than dispatched as an `ErrorEvent`.

It can be detected by using a `try...catch` block instead:

```
function loadImage (): void 
{
    var _imageLoader = new Loader();
    _imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, imageSecurityErrorEventListener);
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("this-image-not-exits.jpg");

    try
    {
        _imageLoader.load(request);
    }
    catch (error:Error)
    {
        trace("A different error was thrown, not dispatched as an ErrorEvent");
    }
}
```

For a full list of all errors thrown or dispatched as Events, see the Adobe language reference page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load()

Comment: when I try this the same error will be traced. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps listen to the loader directly instead of its contentLoaderInfo? `_imageLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, imageSecurityErrorEventListener);`